# i'm trying to do an android application that captures an image and matches it with some images stored in sqlite database then it warns the user

Tags: android, sqlite

After I had searched I found that it is better to store all the data of the       sqlite database in an XML file and then extract the data from it. I have tried but each time there is some errors that i could not understand.

Is there any better way to achieve my goal?

This is the code for creating the database:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String dataBase_Name="dbProject";
    private static final String table_name="dbImages";
    private static final int database_version=1;
    private static final String UID="id";    
    private static final String NAME="name";    
    private static final String IMAGE="images";
    private static final String Create_Images_Table= "CREATE TABLE "+table_name
            +" (" +UID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREAMENT , "+NAME
            +" VARCHAR(255) , " +IMAGE +" Blob );";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {  
        super(context, dataBase_Name, null,database_version);
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {

        super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(Create_Images_Table);
        Log.v("DbAdapter", "Image Table Created.");
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

here is the code of the xml file

```
  <p>
        <content>
            <name> black board </name>
            <images> blackboard.bmp</images>
        </content>
        <content>
            <name> chair </name>
            <images>chair.bmp</images>
        </content>
        <content>
            <name>desk</name>
            <images>desk.bmp</images>
        </content>
        <content>
            <name> door </name>
            <images>door.bmp</images>
        </content>
        <content>
            <name>glass window</name>
            <images>glassWindow.bmp</images>
        </content>
        <content>
            <name> wall </name>
            <images> wall.bmp </images>
        </content>
        <content>
            <name>window</name>
            <images>window.bmp</images>
        </content>
        <content>
            <name>wooden chair</name>
            <images>woodenChair.bmp</images>
        </content>

    </p>
```

and here is the error I receive:

> Error:Error: Unsupported type 'p'

Comment: What error messages do you receive? Add them to your question. Also, you misspelled "AUTOINCREMENT" in your `Create_Images_Table` variable.

Comment: oh thanks for help  @BrokenBinary  . ok it gives me this message Error:Error: Unsupported type 'p'. and here is the code of the xml file

Comment: why it does not accept <p> @Broken ?